# what to do to render the whole document in APA style(font-spacing, pagenumbering in head)

Tags: apa-style

here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,lmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,skip=0.5\baselineskip,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{distbib.bib}
\begin{document}
\include{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\eject
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{intro}
\include{chap23}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered switching the document to `apa6`?

Comment: when I switched to apa6, some package don't match so it does not compile

Comment: AFAICT, the *only* package from your preamble that reports an options clash with the `apa6` document class is the `geometry` package. Since your professed goal is to apply APA style to the entire document, the obvious solution is to stop loading the `geometry` package in the preamble. Incidentally, the option `labelfont=bf` in the `\captionsetup` instruction would appear to be in conflict with the prescribed look of the `apa6` document class (which requires non-bold italics).

Comment: I did but the \include{files} stop the compilation.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to. I don't see an `\include{files}` instruction in your code. (Aside: My divination skills are sadly non-existent.)

Comment: I mean \include{chapter1}, \include{chapter2}, \include{chapter3}, .... which are consisted in the document and they are huge files to load here.

Comment: and inside there are :\chapter{}, \section{}, figures, tables, etc

Comment: So, please please edit your query to indicate what's actually going on in your document. Otherwise, it's impossible to determine which issues you are facing. BTW, are you claiming that the presence of `figure` and `table` environments in the subfiles is creating a problem under the `apa6` document class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105997/discussion-between-chamanga-and-mico).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm at a location behind a firewall that blocks all access to chatrooms.

Comment: ok, i modified the query so you can see it is structured. ASAP, the compilation process reach \include{Abstract} it stops eeven if i remove everything in the abstract file, of course under \document[man]{apa6}

Comment: You should be getting a really easy-to-interpret error message as soon as LaTeX gets to the first `\chapter` instruction -- the `apa6` and `apa7` document classes do not provide a definition of `\chapter`. You will need to manually change all `\chapter` commands to `\section`, all `\section` commands to `\subsection`, etc.

Comment: I changed all, till now it doesn't compile. when it reaches \include{chap} it stops. i changed all chapter to section and section to subsection